# Raspberry PI 4 Chia Farm 20 HDD 2 USB Hubs

Tags: usb, hard-drive, raspberry-pi-os, troubleshooting

I have a huge problem.

I have 20 HDD and 2 usb 16slot hubs. And if I connect the two hubs than everything is fine and works fine if the total number of hdd is over 19 rasbian OS 64 bit disconnects all of them.

Im hardcore desperate I tried it with other hubs even putting the hub into the hub and stuff but nothing seems to work. And sometimes 10 hdd got recognized and sometimes its 15. It seems completly random. And no the heater is not on its broken the chia farm is now my heater. When its runnnign it takes 120watts. in the back is one powerline and all 3 10slot power lines are connected wiuth that in the back. everything has power. the main powerline is in the socket.
I used for the internal hdd the external conectors.

One more question rasbian unmounts and disconnect the hdd. But I can only ge tthem to show up if im restarting the pi is there a other option?

Would be awesome if someone cna help me.

[image: Chia Farm]

Comment: what is your specific question? ... please do not depend on an implied question ... it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: I have 20 drives when I connect one at a time at 15 sometimes at 18 drives all get unmounted and not showing up on the pi. all the time. Sometimes 16 works fine than they suddendly all disconnect. I checked all and conected the two hubs on a othe rmachine at the usb 2 port and it works. I dotn knwo how to solve this problem.

Comment: still no direct question ... are you asking `how to troubleshoot such a problem?`

Comment: My question Why raspbian disconnects all my hdd's for no reason and without giving me and epxlanation why they are disconnecting. And how can I make them show up again without rebooting the whole thing.

Comment: my first guess would be a power issue ... check voltages

Comment: I also thought of that. but the usb hubs are powered. it seems strange. Maybe the pi is underpowered. What im also currently chekcing is the driver for the usb mounting got some problems. I will try windows 11 on the raspberry now. It seems like a software OS problem and not like a hardware problem. But yes it also could be maybe that the pi is giving to much power over usb even if he doesnt need to maybe thats also a problem. I will check that with windows and if that doesnt work. Than I can atleast cry in a corner and can say atleast I tried xD Party Hard

Comment: have installed windows, dont seem to work switchting on and off drives work on my normal pc 20 evne on one usb2 port no problem. but on the pi no chance. even with shitty windows.

Comment: I now still have no clue.On anormal PC this works fine. Even on small shit pc. I dont know what the raspberry pi devs did tot his thing but its horrible. Why does thier usb not work like every other usb in the world wtf.

Comment: First clear out all the old log message  **dmesg -c**   Then trigger the problem, and then do **dmesg** again without the -c.  What does the logs say about this?

Comment: nothing works, all drives got unmounted and than this in the error log but what it means and how to solve:
</>Feb 11 17:54:02 raspberrypi kernel: [ 640.987378] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 CDB: opcode=0x85 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
Feb 11 17:54:02 raspberrypi kernel: [ 640.999346] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host not

Comment: Feb 11 17:54:02 raspberrypi kernel: [ 640.999355] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: USBSTS: HSE EINT
Feb 11 17:54:02 raspberrypi kernel: [ 641.031364] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host halt failed, -110
Feb 11 17:54:02 raspberrypi kernel: [ 641.031368] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Feb 11 17:54:02 raspberrypi kernel: [ 641.031667] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
Feb 11 17:54:02 raspberrypi kernel: [ 641.031840] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Feb 11 17:54:02 raspberrypi kernel: [ 641.031852] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3